# SharePoint List tables

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on a project for work, and I'm attempting to move data from a database with multiple references to different tables.
My question is; is it possible to move the data and be able to have a list that references different lists? For example, when I click on an element in the list, can I create another "link" to take me to another list?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if I understand the problem well You would like to create some kind of column in one list which will store reference to item from other list, correct?
If so then You are looking for lookup columns. When adding column to a list You may select lookup column type, after that You need to select which list You would like to 'reference' and which column should be present from the second list in the lookup column from the first list. Please check the reference [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: Thanks a ton, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

OOB lookup column(similar concept as database foreign key) will be good, while [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) will be helpful for complex scenario also.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the feedback!